# Difference between readAsDataURL() and readAsArrayBuffer() and readAsText() in JavaScript FileReader

Tags: javascript, html

I have found a code of image uploading preview, I'm confused what's going on in `FileRead()` ?

```
var openFile = function(event) {
    var input = event.target;

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
        var dataURL = reader.result;
        var output = document.getElementById('output');
        console.log(dataURL)
        output.src = dataURL;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
};
```

Comment: Well the words after `readAs` tell you want you are reading the data as ... What is your specific question?

Comment: This is all explained in the documentation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- `.readAsDataURL()` return a URL representing the file's data as a
  base64 encoded string
- `.readAsArrayBuffer()` return an ArrayBuffer representing the file's 
  data
- `.readAsText()` return the file's data as a text string.

For more info check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) `FileReader` doc.

Answer (score 8):

I think if you want to have a file upload functionality and then show the user a preview of the file they they chose from their PC and about to upload, then use `.readAsDataURL()`.

If you want to manipulate a text file, use `.readAsText()`

If you want to manipulate something like an image (convert a jpeg to PNG for example) then use `.readAsArrayBuffer()`.

There is a fourth method, `.readAsBinaryString`, but the Mozilla documentation suggests using `.readAsArrayBuffer()` instead.

Answer (score 6):

`readAsDataURL()` will return a string that can be pasted into the url attribute of an HTML tag (e.g.: `src=` in an img). For an `img` tag, that will effectively display the image just like if `src` was an address to the file that was read. It is a transformation (bigger) of the original file content.

`readAsText()` will return a string of characters that can be parsed by JavaScript functions or displayed in textarea and likely to be understood by the user. This is usually useful for reading text files.